# Units of time calculation in R

Tags: r, datetime, for-loop, time, posix

This is a sample of the data I have.I have columns with the read dates.I converted the readdate column into date format using the function as.POSIXct().

```
data$readdate=as.POSIXct(data$readdate,format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

ID   readdate                   tdiff
A    2016-06-01 06:00:06          0
B    2016-06-01 06:01:06          1
C    2016-06-01 06:03:06          2
D    2016-06-01 06:04:06          1
E    2016-06-01 06:04:56          50
F    2016-06-01 08:04:56          2
```

I need the third column tdiff to show the time elapsed between two ID's.I used a loop and

```
for(i in 1:nrow(data)){
tdiff=data$readdate[i+1]-data$readdate[i]}
```

The problem with using this method is R rounds up the units of the time.I want the tdiff column to consist of a single type of units(such as seconds or mins) similar to this

```
ID   readdate                   tdiff(seconds)  or tdiff(mins)
A    2016-06-01 06:00:06          0                    0
B    2016-06-01 06:01:06          60                   1
C    2016-06-01 06:03:06          120                  2
D    2016-06-01 06:04:06          60                   1
E    2016-06-01 06:04:56          50                   0.5
F    2016-06-01 08:04:56          7200                 120
```

I need all of them to be similar, because later I have to extract all IDs which have a tdiff of greater than 30 mins.

Comment: are you sure that in the E row there should be 40 and not 50 ?

Comment: It should just be a `diff` operation - `c(0, diff(dat$readdate))` maybe?

Comment: yes @storaged ,it is 50

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest is to use `difftime` with the unit you want from `c("auto", "secs", "mins", "hours", " days", "weeks")`

For seconds use:

```
difftime(data$readdate[i+1], data$readdate[i], units="secs")
```

Comment: this is what I was looking for @storaged ,Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should just be a `diff` operation, which will dispatch to `diff.POSIXt`:

```
dif <- diff(dat$readdate)
dif
#Time differences in secs
#[1]   60  120   60   50 7200
c(0, dif)
#[1]    0   60  120   60   50 7200
```

If you need to change the units of measurement, just do so using `units<-`

```
units(dif) <- "mins"
c(0, dif)
#[1]   0.0000000   1.0000000   2.0000000   1.0000000   0.8333333 120.0000000
```

You can also do this in-line if you are tricky:

```
c(0, `units<-`(diff(dat$readdate), "mins"))
#[1]   0.0000000   1.0000000   2.0000000   1.0000000   0.8333333 120.0000000
```